# problem on linking sqlite to xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, sqlite, linker-errors

I use fmdatabase for my sqlite project, i add lib to my frameworks and could run on simulator, when i want to release my project have a linking error.
does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at capital and small letters. Device is different from Simulator in that point. Your letters must be the same. Also try to read error message, it helps a lot. It is also possible that you have different SDK version(iOS) on device and Simulator. Check it.